# Pandas implicit type casting from index to series

Tags: python, pandas

This works:

```
    s['Date'] = s.index.get_level_values('Date')
    s['Expire Days'] = (pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) - s['Date'])
```

But this does not:

```
    s['Expire Days'] = (pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) - s.index.get_level_values('Date'))
```

The error is:

```
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer_non_unique (pandas/index.c:6148)()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

s is a Pandas DataFrame with a multi-index.

I'm mostly interested in why one works and not the other. As I see it, both should work.

Comment: Try `s['Expire Days'] = (pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) - s.index.get_level_values('Date').to_series())`

Comment: Produces the error: "Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented." 
Date will not be unique on it's own, it's part of a multi-index.

Comment: Yes, I get same error. So one possible solution is working with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for converting `Series` to `numpy array`:

```
s['Expire Days'] = pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']).values - 
                   s.index.get_level_values('Date')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame({'Expiration': {(pd.Timestamp('2015-03-04 00:00:00'), 1): '2015-03-05', 
                                 (pd.Timestamp('2015-03-03 00:00:00'), 2): '2015-03-05'}})
s = s.rename_axis(['Date','a'])
print (s)
              Expiration
Date       a            
2015-03-03 2  2015-03-05
2015-03-04 1  2015-03-05


s['Expire Days'] = pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']).values - 
                    s.index.get_level_values('Date')
print (s)
              Expiration  Expire Days
Date       a                         
2015-03-04 1  2015-03-05       1 days
2015-03-03 1  2015-03-05       2 days
```

EDIT by comment:

```
s['Date'] = s.index.get_level_values('Date')
s['Expire Days'] = (pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) - s['Date'])
```

work nice, because `ndarray` as output of [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) is converted to `Series` in column `Expire Days`.

---

```
s['Expire Days'] = (pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) - s.index.get_level_values('Date'))
```

doesnt work, pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) is `Series` and `s.index.get_level_values('Date')` is `ndarray`. So you need both numpy arrays or both Series.

And because error:

> "Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented."

in `pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration']) - s.index.get_level_values('Date').to_series()`, use converting both to `ndarray`.

Comment: Well I agree this works, but I don't understand *why* it works. Furthermore, is ordering guaranteed given the 'indexless' casting of numpy?

Comment: I think ordering is not problem, because output is array, not dictionary.

Comment: To be honest, I understand this works, but it doesn't really answer my original question, which is *why* one works and not the other.

Comment: Sorry. It doesnt work, because output of `s.index.get_level_values('Date')` is numpy array and output of `(pd.to_datetime(s['Expiration'])` is Series. So I think you need both numpy arrays or both `Series`.

Comment: If check [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), output is `values : ndarray`.